# How do I disable the confirmation email sent out from Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6.19. I don't want users to receive confirmation email on registration.

For this I unchecked "`Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account`" in Admin > User management > user settings.

But now what happens is that the verification email has been changed to confirmation email. i.e no verification link is there but the still the mail is sent out from the website with the user credentials. I do not need the mail at all. Could anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll need to write a custom module that has hook_form_alter and looks for submission of the registration form. You *could* hack away at the user module but then any updates will overwrite your changes.

Looks like user_Registration_submit makes a couple of conditional calls to _user_mail_notify which you probably want to catch and stop.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_register_submit/6

Initially I'd comment out those lines and register to confirm that they are responsible for the mail. If they are then you can try and see what you can do to step in and stop that call...

Hope that helps

Answer (score 8):

In `Drupal 7`, the conf variable you should add the following line in your settings.php

```
$conf['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = FALSE;
```

The bold could take this value :

- `register_admin_created`: Welcome message for user created by the
  admin.
- `register_no_approval_required`: Welcome message when user
  self-registers.
- `register_pending_approval`: Welcome message, user
  pending admin approval.
- `password_reset`: Password recovery request.
- `status_activated`: Account activated.
- `status_blocked`: Account
  blocked.
- `cancel_confirm`: Account cancellation request.
- `status_canceled`: Account canceled.

Be careful, it's `user_mail_YOUR_VARIABLE_notify`  .

Docs [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7) and [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_register_submit/7).

Thanks for previous answers !

Comment: is there a drush solution for this?

Comment: This saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of message you need to disable, do the following ...

Add something looking like the following line in your settings.php

$conf['user_mail_**register_no_approval_required_notify**'] = FALSE;

Replace the part in bold with the proper email message code. Some possible values are:

- register_admin_created
- register_no_approval_required_notify
- register_pending_approval
- password_reset
- status_activated
- status_blocked
- status_deleted

Answer (score 0):

There is now a module called Mail Control that takes care of this desire.
http://drupal.org/project/mailcontrol

It allows you say you don't want to send the User Welcome mail, and swap it out for Rules if you like, or just leave that part out of the experience.

This could be really useful if you were migrating in tons of users, or for a lightweight ecommerce site (which is why I needed it).

Drupal 7 and Drupal 6 handle this differently behind the scenes, but I think MailControl still puts the checkboxes at the same place in the User Admin UI.